# Default port number of CVS

Tags: cvs

Can anybody help me with the default port number used for CVS repository.

regards,
PK

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`grep cvs /etc/services` says 2401, both TCP and UDP. Of course, using it over SSH will use port 22 instead.

Comment: i am trying to connect using SSH2. so it would be using port : 22? I need to raise a request to open some firewall, that's y

Answer (score 10):

The default `pserver` port is 2401 but, of course, that's no guarantee that your particular server will be using that port. However, since you asked for the default, 2401 is the answer.